# JS regex match (doesn't begin with [A-z]+://)www

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I have some links in which people did not add the protocol to.  I.e., www.stackoverflow.com.  If the link begins with www., I want to replace it with 'http://www.'.

How can I do this with JavaScript regular expressions?

I tried the code below, but I can't seem to match the pattern 'doesn't start with [A-z]+://www.'.

The links are mixed in with text.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {       
    jQuery('.myClass').each(function (index) {
        var temp = wwwify(jQuery(this).text());
        jQuery(this).html(temp);
    });
});

function wwwify(text) {
    var regex = /(?!\b([A-z]+:\/\/))www\./igm;
    return text.replace(regex, 'http://www.');
}
```

Comment: For now I'm making two passes through the text:
'function wwwLineBeginsWith(text) {
    var regex = /^www\./gi;
    return text.replace(regex, 'http://www.');
}

function wwwWordBeginsWith(text) {
    var regex = /\swww\./gi;
    return text.replace(regex, ' http://www.');
}'

Not sure if there's a better way

Comment: **Warning:** It is an error to use the range `[A-z]` in regexes.  It matches the uppercase and lowercase ASCII letters as you would expect, but it also matches several punctuation characters whose code points happen to lie between `Z` and `a`.  The correct way to perform a case-insensitive match is with the `i` modifier, which you're already using.  (I didn't downvote; this is just general advice.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I haven't found any suitable regex solutions through SO or elsewhere, just using regular javascript replace may be the best solution.

For now I'm making two passes through the text:

```
function wwwLineBeginsWith(text) { 
    var regex = /^www./gi; 
    return text.replace(regex, 'http://'); 
} 

function wwwWordBeginsWith(text) { 
    var regex = /\swww./gi; return text.replace(regex, 'http://'); 
}

var test1 = 'www.test2.com';
test1 = wwwLineBeginsWith(test1);
test1 = wwwWordBeginsWith(test1);

console.log(wwwWordBeginsWith(test1));
```

Comment: This doesn’t answer your question, as far as I can tell. Mind explaining?

Comment: @minitech I didn't really explain my answer well before. I added some more text, realized I forgot to update the replacement string, and added some text to try and elaborate. I also commented on your proposed answer. Doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the following?

```
if (text.substring(0,4)=='www.') {
    text = 'http://'+text;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to search anywhere in the string (see `igm` flags).

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor your regex to the start of the string. Also the range needs to be `/[a-z]/` as the `/i` modifier will cover the upper-case possibilities. The `/m` and `/g` modifiers are irrelevant here. Leaving

```
var regex = /^(?![a-z]+:\/\/)www\./i;
```

---

My apologies, I missed the part saying "The links are mixed in with text". Without look-behind this can only be done using a function to return a replacement string. I suggest this, which captures any protocol before the *www.* and replaces it with *http://* if it is blank

```
var regex = /\b([a-z]+:\/\/)?www\./ig;

text.replace(regex, function(url, protocol) {
    return protocol ? url : "http://" + url;
});
```

Comment: -1, wrong. The `/g` modifier is there to replace everywhere in the string, look at the documentation. Also, there's nothing about anchoring to the start. Finally, although using `[a-z]` instead of `[A-z]` is better in this case, it wouldn't do anything to solve the problem regardless.

Comment: @minitech: thanks - I misread the problem. I have updated my solution. Even so the `/m` modifier remains irrrelevant.

Comment: @minitech: `[A-z]` is wrong in any case.  It may have been a typo in this instance, but many people do try to use that as a shorthand for uppercase and lowercase letters.  We should always call attention to this error when we see it, because if we don't, our silence will be interpreted as an endorsement.

Answer (score 0):

You could just easily replace each "http://www." to "www." and then replace all "www." to "http://www.". It might not be the prettiest regexp you could imagine, but it will solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.myClass').each(function (index) {
    var $elm = $(this); // cache $(this) for reuse
    var html = $elm.html();
    html = html.replace(/http\:\/\/www\./ig, "www.").replace(/www\./ig, "http://www."); ;
    $elm.html(html);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

How about replacing those with a protocol regardless?

```
function wwwify(text) {
    return text.replace(/(http(s?):\/\/)?www\./ig, 'http$2://www.');
}
```

The reason it's currently not working is because JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, only lookaheads. You would need the syntax `(?<!`, which is not available in JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: unfortunately a link like https://www.stackexchange.com would then be converted to https:// http:// www.stackexchange.com (ignore the spaces - stackoverlfow is modifying my post

Comment: @Hoppe: Oh, okay. That's fixed now.

Comment: @Hoppe: Does it work now? I added support for `https://`. You can do the same for FTP if necessary.

Comment: The problem is that this replaces https with http

Comment: Don't know who downvoted, but your fiddle doesn't work. Is it out of date? I.e. it doesn't convert to www.stackoverflow.com to http://www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Hoppe: The fiddle’s working fine for me, but jsFiddle has been a little unstable of late… try it full-page: http://jsfiddle.net/UzUjZ/show/

Comment: @Hoppe: Try the fiddle again.

Answer (score -2):

If you absolutely must use RegExp to determine this, I would recommend using something like `/^[^Hh][^Tt]{2}[^Pp]:\/\//` for the RegExp. Otherwise, I agree with the other posters... using indexOf would be far easier (i.e., `url.toLowerCase().indexOf('http://') !== 0`).

Comment: Read the question, there can be many URLs in the string and they're not necessarily at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I did read the question, and I don't read into it the same as you apparently ("I have some links..."). The OP wants to test each link. Each link should start with the HTTP protocol. I respectfully submit that if there are many URLs to test in each string, perhaps a `.split()` is called for, and that a RegExp is probably not the best solution for this problem.

Comment: Actually, a regular expression is almost the only solution. And by "read the question" I meant read the code, too. The `/igm` flags at the end of the regular expression are there for a reason.

Comment: @minitech: you mean that code that doesn't work?! It isn't reasonable to expect contributors to gain information from code submitted by the OP which is known to be incorrect. His `/m` is wrong and it wasn't unlikely that the `/g` was also incorrect. People often scatter `/igms` after regexes as a catch-all.

Comment: @Borodin: Actually, the `/g` was correct, the `/i` would have helped a lot here, and yes I mean the code that doesn't work.

Comment: To who ever downvoted, please let me know how my answer was not helpful so I can improve it.